# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `product' for :outlet_product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm doing the edit page for OutletProduct which store product_id and outlet_id.

At the edit page the product name and outlet name should show original one. But now i can't show the product and outlet name out.

Also it show me some error.

OutletProduct controller

```
def edit
 @outlet_product = OutletProduct.find(params[:id])
end

def update
 @outlet_product = OutletProduct.find(params[:id])
 if @outlet_product.update(outlet_product_params)
   flash[:success] = "Outlet Product updated"
   redirect_to @outlet_product
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: @outlet_product, local: true) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :product_name %>
   <%= f.text_field @outlet_product.product.name, class: 'form-control'%>

   <%= f.label :quantity %>
   <%= f.number_field :quantity%>

   <%= f.label :selling_price %>
   <%= f.number_field :selling_price, class: 'form-control' %>

   <%= f.label :last_cost %>
   <%= f.number_field :last_cost, class: 'form-control' %>

   <%= f.label :outlet_id %>
   <%= f.text_field @outlet_product.outlet.name, class: 'form-control'%>


   <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

[error in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS7Q3.png)

[UI edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ZRk.png)

Update

[OutletProduct call in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsFr0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra '**:**' here: `<%= f.text_field : @outlet_product.product.name%>`, and the error is telling you it thinks **@outlet_product** is a symbol, but you are treating it like an object!

You are doing it correctly slightly lower down:

```
<%= f.text_field: @outlet_product.outlet.name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

so just do the same and remove the '**:**'

Comment: HI, it solve the error but how can i show the outlet name out?

Comment: I mean i have to guess here, but this looks about right **@outlet_product.outlet.name**. are you sure you have a name set for outlet?

Comment: yes, at outlet table i have name and address

Comment: at create there i also have let admin choose the product and outlet. It also succesfully create but at edit page it can't show the outlet and product name

Comment: I have edit my edit.html.erb code and also the pic of ui. I think direct use the product.name and outlet.name maybe can, but it show me some number on the input, can you help me to see what happen

Comment: you just edited the **@outlet_product.outlet.name**, but that should work as long as the associated **outlet** has a name. I dont think your edit/change just now (**:product.name** and **:outlet.name**) will work. Although did just learn that you can call ```.name``` on a symbol which is why it didnt error :)

Comment: hmmm, but it didn't come out, the product name also didn't come out. I have update my question with the pic i call OutletProduct in console,  i need to get the outlet name through the outlet.id inside the OutletProduct

Comment: Well we fixed your initial error at least, so I hope that means you can trouble shoot a little more from here on out and I cant (and going by the stack overflow rules probably shouldnt) use the comment section to debug a larger app/feature im only loosely familiar with.